# Keep special characters when importing into mysql from csv

Tags: mysql, csv, import

I have a csv file which contains special characters. However, when I import them into my table they do not import. I have the row that needs to contain special characters setup as utf8_general_ci

However, I am losing the special characters upon phpmyadmin import. For example, the degree symbol is not importing. I viewed my csv file in a text editor and it does contain the special characters.

Please help.

Ok, I figured how to do this. See my answer below.

Answer (score 15):

Only needs change the charset in mysql when try to upload the file.
In my case works the charset windows-1252

[image: Charset on mysql]

Answer (score 9):

Ok,

for anyone who has this same issue trying to keep the exported csv file in utf8 while keeping the special characters do the following.

Open up your file in OpenOffice Calc. When you get ready to save it save it as text csv file. While exporting it will ask you what format to save it as. Save it as UTF8 and presto. It does not convert your special characters like excel does.

Hope that helps someone else.

Comment: Thank you - that worked! Actually did this with EmEditor. Opened a file, and then saved it as "UTF-8 Without Signature".

Answer (score 4):

Excel usually outputs CSV as UTF-16, but there are ways to get it to output in UTF-8 as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4221176/857209)

If you are on Windows you can also use the standard Notepad text editor to convert the file by selecting UTF-8 encoding in the **Save As** dialog as shown below:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Try to convert the charset of your csv file to utf8.
For exemple with Notepad++

```
Encoding -> Convert to UTF-8 without BOM
```

Comment: Thanks I downloaded Notepadd++ When viewing the file in that I see odd character replacements. I then convert it and I still see the odd characters. However, when viewing in another text editor I see the correct symbols. Any idea?

Comment: You know the charset of your file ? By default, Notepad++ open the files with ANSI charset, maybe that your file is encoded in another charset...

Comment: It should be utf8 but I converted it to that and still see the issue

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you must check setup as csv file. I think you problem begin in this file. Check this and make sure that both coding were the same(csv and sql table)

Comment: Thanks for the tip. How do I check it and change it?

Comment: Please check this: http://office.microsoft.com/en-gb/word-help/choose-text-encoding-when-you-open-and-save-files-HA102004472.aspx?CTT=1

Comment: Table check in phpmyadmin