# phpmyadmin escaping backslashes while importing from external csv file

Tags: php, mysql, csv, phpmyadmin

I have  saved mathjax tex commands in mysql database. The mathjax tex commands
have backshlases in them. For ex. $\frac{x}{y}$. When I tried to export this table
in csv format by using phpmyadmin, everything worked fine. But, when I tried to
import it back, the data got imported escaping backslash characters. How to fix this?

Comment: It might be an issue of encoding, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21242413/

Comment: No that is not issue. Both export and import are in utf-8 format.

Comment: And no escaping parameters are available in PhpMyAdmin import page ? Tell if they are backslashes escaped in .csv file to determine if it comes from import or export.

Comment: There is no problem with export. Backslashes are in exported file. But, while importing the same previously exported file, the backslashes are eliminated.

Comment: If backslashes are in exported file, there might be a misconfiguration with your export. Could you show a screenshot of your export configuration page ?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I'm now using xml format for export and import. Everything works fine in this format. But, there is still problem with csv format.

Comment: This is not the answer of the question asked.